# Python 3 PriorityDeque with absolute priorities

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread-safety, scheduled-tasks

Python 3 has `queue.PriorityQueue`, but that wasn't good enough (lacking methods, not double-ended, etc) for me and my purposes. Therefore, I have made a new one based on a dictionary of `collection.deque`s.

I am well aware that this is a naive implementation, because it uses 5 times as many `collections.deque`s as a smart Python implementation would. This is mostly because I couldn't figure out how to simply implement efficient search (for finding ranges of one priority in the deque) without looking at almost every element.

This is supposed to be thread-safe (as far as that can go in CPython) but it also doesn't seem to break when shared between PyPy `stackless` tasklets.

There are a finite number of priorities a thing can have. This is what is meant by "absolute priorties". The priority of an entry is meaningful without considering the priorities of other objects in the queue.

Compare this with the Linux kernel, whose processes are given a number from -19 (most nice) to 20 (least nice) which determines how they will be scheduled with respect to one another. This is effective because, like any task scheduler, the kernel will probably come back to run every process at some point.

However, the `priority_deque` is designed not for "re-entrant access" to each entry like a long-running process scheduler needs, but rather one-time access to the ends of the deque(s).

And so with absolute priorities the five-section `priority_deque` acts somewhat like a contiguous datastructure, in that its most privileged entries are preferred (by default) over the least privileged ones.

Note finally that the highest priority `deque`s are of very finite size. Normally, this would result in the oldest (and arguably most important) entries being shoved off the other end of the `deque` to make room for the new entries (as the `maxlen` argument normally does).

This implementation uses `deque.maxlen` to prevent losing important entries and instead scheduling new entries at the top end of a longer, less important `deque`.

[GitHub](https://github.com/catb0t/transactor/blob/master/prioritydeque.py)

**prioritydeque.py**

```
import enum


@enum.unique
class priority(enum.IntEnum):
    undef, low, normal, high, airmail = range(-1, 4)

    def describe(self):
        return self.value, self.name

    @classmethod
    def min(cls):
        return min(
            [e.describe() for e in list(cls)],
            key=lambda x: x[0]
        )

    @classmethod
    def max(cls):
        return max(
            [e.describe() for e in list(cls)],
            key=lambda x: x[0]
        )


DEFAULT_MAXLENS = {
    priority.undef:   None,
    priority.low:     None,
    priority.normal:  None,
    priority.high:    50,
    priority.airmail: 10
}


def get_maxlen(params, key):
    return params.get(key, DEFAULT_MAXLENS[key])


class priority_deque():
    """
        Base class for priority deque objects.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def default_nice_sorter(nices):
        return sorted(nices, key=lambda x: x.value, reverse=True)

    @staticmethod
    def random_nice_sorter(nices):
        import random
        return random.shuffle(nices, len(nices))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            params: priority_enum ** (an alternative enum class with the same
                        member names as the priority class)
            retval: a blank priority_deque
            raises: AttributeError if priority_enum has an unexpected set
                        of names
            purity: yes

            Create an empty priority deque.
        """
        import threading
        from collections import deque
        self.prty = priority
        if "priority_enum" in kwargs:
            self.prty = kwargs["priority_enum"]
        self._pool = {
            self.prty.undef:
                deque(maxlen=get_maxlen(kwargs, self.prty.undef)),
            self.prty.low:
                deque(maxlen=get_maxlen(kwargs, self.prty.low)),
            self.prty.normal:
                deque(maxlen=get_maxlen(kwargs, self.prty.normal)),
            self.prty.high:
                deque(maxlen=get_maxlen(kwargs, self.prty.high)),
            self.prty.airmail:
                deque(maxlen=get_maxlen(kwargs, self.prty.airmail))
        }
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def push(
        self, obj, want_nice=None, force=False,
        want_push_func=lambda q, o: q.appendleft(o),
        settle_push_func=lambda q, o: q.append(o)
    ):
        """
            params: obj (an object)
                    want_nice ** (a priority; default: self.prty.normal)
                    force ** (a bool; default: false)
                    want_push_func ** (a function q, o -> None;
                        default: appendleft)
                    settle_push_func ** (a function q, o -> None;
                        default: append)
            retval: None (a NoneType)
                    nice (a priority; the priority that obj ended up with)
            raises: KeyError if nice is not a key in self.prty (that is, it
                        is not a key in self._pool)
            purity: relative

            Add a new entry to the pool, with the maximum priority of nice.
            The entry may end up with a lower priority because all the other
                deques were full.

            obj can be pushed to the top (right side) of a deque by specifying
                push_func like (lambda q, o: q.append(o)).
            If the preferred nice value want_nice is full and force=False,
                settle_push_func will be used to "settle for" a lower nice
                value.
            By default, this secondary function pushes to the top of the next
                lowest priority.

            If force=False, this method is not destructive; it will try to
                push on a deque in the pool which is not full.
            To force pushing an object into a specific priority even if they
                are full, set force=True.
        """
        import time
        if want_nice is None:
            want_nice = self.prty.normal
        if force or self._can_push(want_nice):
            time.sleep(0)
            with self.lock:
                return want_push_func(self._pool[want_nice], obj), want_nice

        # start from the highest priority and go down
        nices = range(want_nice, priority.min()[0])
        for nice in nices:
            # nice != want_nice
            time.sleep(0)
            if self._can_push(nice):
                    with self.lock:
                        return settle_push_func(self._pool[nice], obj), nice

    def pop(
        self, force_nice=(False, None),
        nice_sorter=None, pop_func=lambda q: q.pop()
    ):
        """
            params: force_nice ** (a pair<bool, priority>;
                        default: (Force, None))
                    nice_sorter ** (a function n -> s;
                        default: priority_deque.default_nice_sorter)
                    pop_func ** (a function q -> o; default: pop)
            retval: obj (an object)
                    nice (a priority; the priority obj had)
            raises: KeyError if force_nice isn't long enough
                    KeyError if force_nice[1] is not a key in self.prty
            purity: relative

            Remove an entry from the pool.
            By default, looks for the highest-priority items first.
            The priority of the resulting object is returned alongside it.
            If no object was found, an object of None and a priority of None
                are returned.

            The deques are sorted by nice_sorter, and the highest-priority non-
                empty deque is popped from with pop_func.
            To look for lower priorities first, use a function which does not
                reverse-sort the priority list.
            To use a random priority, use self.random_nice_sorter
            To pop from a specific priority, use force_nice=(True, nice).
            This will return an object or None (if the priority was empty) and
                the provided priority.
        """
        import time
        if nice_sorter is None:
            nice_sorter = self.default_nice_sorter
        if force_nice[0]:
            time.sleep(0)
            with self.lock:
                return pop_func(self._pool[ force_nice[1] ]), force_nice[1]

        nices = self._sort_pool(nice_sorter)
        for nice in nices:
            time.sleep(0)
            dq = self._pool[nice]
            if len(dq):
                with self.lock:
                    return pop_func(dq), nice
        return None, None

    def peek(
        self, force_nice=(False, None),
        nice_sorter=None, peek_func=lambda q: q[-1]
    ):
        """
            params: force_nice ** (a pair<bool, priority>;
                        default: (Force, None))
                    nice_sorter ** (a function n -> s;
                        default: priority_deque.default_nice_sorter)
                    pop_func ** (a function q -> o;
                        default: lambda q: q[-1])
            retval: obj (an object)
                    nice (a priority; the priority obj has)
            raises: KeyError if force_nice isn't long enough
                    KeyError if force_nice[1] is not a key in self.prty
            purity: relative

            View an entry in the pool.
        """
        if nice_sorter is None:
            nice_sorter = self.default_nice_sorter
        if force_nice[0]:
            with self.lock:
                return peek_func(self._pool[ force_nice[1] ]), force_nice[1]
        return self.pop(nice_sorter=nice_sorter, pop_func=peek_func)

    def clear1(self, nice):
        dq = self._pool[nice].copy()
        with self.lock:
            self._pool[nice].clear()
        return dq

    def clear(self):
        pool = self._pool.copy()
        for nice in self.prty:
            with self.lock:
                self._pool[nice].clear()
        return pool

    def _sort_pool(self, nice_sorter=default_nice_sorter):
        return nice_sorter( self.prty )

    def _can_push(self, nice):
        if self._pool[nice].maxlen is None:
            return True
        return len( self._pool[nice] ) < self._pool[nice].maxlen

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._pool)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reviewing the docstring for the `push` method:

```
        params: obj (an object)
                want_nice ** (a priority; default: self.prty.normal)
                force ** (a bool; default: false)
                want_push_func ** (a function q, o -> None;
                    default: appendleft)
                settle_push_func ** (a function q, o -> None;
                    default: append)
        retval: None (a NoneType)
                nice (a priority; the priority that obj ended up with)
        raises: KeyError if nice is not a key in self.prty (that is, it
                    is not a key in self._pool)
        purity: relative

        Add a new entry to the pool, with the maximum priority of nice.
        The entry may end up with a lower priority because all the other
            deques were full.

        obj can be pushed to the top (right side) of a deque by specifying
            push_func like (lambda q, o: q.append(o)).
        If the preferred nice value want_nice is full and force=False,
            settle_push_func will be used to "settle for" a lower nice
            value.
        By default, this secondary function pushes to the top of the next
            lowest priority.

        If force=False, this method is not destructive; it will try to
            push on a deque in the pool which is not full.
        To force pushing an object into a specific priority even if they
            are full, set force=True.
```

When you find yourself writing a docstring like this, you ought to hear a little voice saying, "hang on a second, this seems awfully complicated!" Complexity in interfaces is costly — it requires time for programmers to understand the interface, it adds maintenance burden, and it increases the number of bugs.

Those are my general concerns, but I have some specific concerns too:

1. The function returns a tuple whose first element is `None` and whose second element is the priority. It would surely be more convenient for the caller if you just returned the priority.
2. The name `want_nice` is the preferred priority for the object, so it would be clearer if this name included the word `priority` somewhere.
3. If `force=True`, then it looks as though objects will be silently discarded when a priority queue is full. This seems likely to be the cause of hard-to-find bugs in applications using the class. Is it really a good idea to provide this flag?
4. Even when `force=False`, it looks as though the object might silently fail to be pushed when all priority queues are full. Again, this seems likely to be the cause of bugs. Failures need to be reported to the caller, for example by raising an exception.
5. There is no documentation for the parameter `want_push_func`. What does this do? Presumably the mention of `push_func` is a typo for `want_push_func`.
6. Presumably the intention is that there are just two valid values for `want_push_func`, namely `lambda q, o: q.appendleft(o)` and `lambda q, o: q.append(o)`. But if this is the case, it should be documented and not just left for the reader to guess.
7. The `want_push_func` interface seems inconvenient: surely it would be better for the `priority_deque` class to have two methods for these two cases? Or if you must have one method with two behaviours, take a flag or an enum instead of a function?
8. The same comments apply to `settle_push_func`: this also needs to be one of two functions, so it really ought to be a flag or enum.
9. `settle_push_func` looks like a bug magnet to me. It is only called in rare circumstances (when a priority queue is full) and so if you made an mistake in writing it then you might not discover the mistake in testing, because it might not be called by your test cases.
10. I can't help but think that in a priority queue system, it shouldn't be necessary to have special mechanisms for pushing on to the front of the queue — if the caller has a higher-priority item, they ought to be able to specify a higher priority. It looks to me as though the design, with a fixed set of priorities and a fixed number of objects at each priority, has created artificial limitations that you then have to try to work around, which leads to complexity in the interface and implementation. When you find yourself in this situation, it's worth taking a step back and trying to see if your design is really meeting your requirements.